# Table Alias - Multiple Foreign Keys Referring to the Same Table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

I can't figure out how to use alias for the tables (I assume that alias is the right approach for my problem). I have table SubContract with 3 fields: SubcontractID, DivisionManager and ServiceManager. Both fields are related to the same table Employee through EmployeeID. The table Employee includes EmployeeID and FirstName fields. I can't figure out how to display FirstName for both DivisionManager and ServiceManager at the same time. I used this approach but still not working:

```
SELECT SubContract.SubContractID, SubContract.DivisionManagerEmployeeID, Employee.FirstName, SubContract.ServiceManagerEmployeeID, Employee.FirstName FROM SubContract 
              
INNER JOIN Employee  Employee1 ON Employee1.EmployeeID = SubContract.DivisionManagerEmployeeID
INNER JOIN Employee  Employee2 ON Employee2.EmployeeID = SubContract.ServiceManagerEmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out:

```
SELECT SubContract.SubContractID, SubContract.DivisionManagerEmployeeID,DivisionManager.FirstName,  SubContract.ServiceManagerEmployeeID, ServiceManager.FirstName 

FROM SubContract

INNER JOIN Employee ServiceManager ON ServiceManager.EmployeeID = SubContract.ServiceManagerEmployeeID
INNER JOIN Employee DivisionManager ON DivisionManager.EmployeeID = SubContract.DivisionManagerEmployeeID
```